# Determinant trick(s)

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Is there a property of determinants that says under some conditions det(A) = det(B) where det(B) is a minor of det(A)? I’m of course asking about other than when A has a row/column of all zeros except for a single 1.

I recall having to solve a 5x5 on an exam without using row reduction. I’m trying to figure out how it would be possible to calculate in a reasonable amount of time. I remeber there was a trick or two that made the problem a lot shorter.

Comment: Depending on what the matrix was (for example block diagonal) you could read off the eigenvalues and note that $\det(A)=\lambda_1 \cdots \lambda_n$ for an $n\times n$ matrix $A$.